# cdi - extension or simple jar with beans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm playing with CDI and would like to get my feets wet with writing extensions.
I'm thinking about standard concept to let users inject configuration properties from file like below:

```
@Inject @Config("applicationUrl")
private String applicationUrl;
```

But I wonder if it is worth doing it as extension? I mean even if I need to use it in several different applications I can just zip all that stuff (ConfigReader, annotations, etc) into tiny jar with beans.xml, and use it as regular beans source. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

[Seam Solder](http://www.seamframework.org/Seam3/Solder) comes with a pretty sophisticated mechanism for [resource injection](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/3.1.0.Final/reference/en-US/html/solder-resourceloading.html). You might want to check this out and see if it covers your needs.

If you are rather looking for opportunities to understand / write / contribute CDI extensions, you will probably get some ideas by following the activities around [Deltaspike](https://cwiki.apache.org/DeltaSpike/) (dont judge the project by its horrible web page :).